# OAuth Login CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE Uber SDK

Tags: uber-api

The email id linked with Uber is: **fikarrnot28@gmail.com**

After successfully logged into user account though the App using LoginManager, the error occurred.

This is the generated GET Request of login in the web view (I have found it when debugging the Uber SDK LoginActivity)...

```
https://auth.uber.com/login/?breeze_local_zone=sjc1&next_url=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.uber.com%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D_AZAHxnjsACGj4oNYtQmHT2BoxLoRslm%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.fikarrnot.com%252FPrivacy-Policy%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dprofile%2Bhistory%2Brequest_receipt%2Brequest%2Ball_trips%26show_fb%3Dfalse%26signup_params%3DeyJyZWRpcmVjdF90b19sb2dpbiI6dHJ1ZX0%253D%250A&state=BpOm3pJ5GOScZSjle7l4hsCKCczTjYO2XvoV8e-RviI%3D
```

...with Headers...

```
[{"key":"X-Requested-With","value":"com.en****rs.fi****not.fi****not","description":""},{"key":"Cookie","value":"utag_main=v_id:01626ccd77e200225dc1cfc5c6c40009801c709000400$_sn:1$_ss:1$_st:1522245627690$ses_id:1522243827690%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$segment:a$optimizely_segment:b; _ga=GA1.2.14743532.1522243830; _gid=GA1.2.1008247445.1522243830; AMCVS_0FEC8C3E55DB4B027F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; aam_uuid=62184944397867583642625051211265352658; AMCV_0FEC8C3E55DB4B027F000101%40AdobeOrg=1611084164%7CMCMID%7C62681591052865814432656684984272277453%7CMCAAMLH-1522848630%7C3%7CMCAAMB-1522848630%7C6G1ynYcLPuiQxYZrsz_pkqfLG9yMXBpb2zX5dvJdYQJzPXImdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1522251030s%7CNONE%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-17626; AAMC_uber_0=AMSYNCSOP%7C411-17626; udid=w_2b967ea663b645cdbd69338871543566; arch-frontend:sess=BAqSPo47olILtPKNMYph-A.Js4qapThHROtKkyZNYsCJC8VwKDpejcPNcDzi8l_zuHUssy_5Xz_FO2swyc1v519menihaos4oCb4GpyKLIjclRD9LlQK79RvjhCnn-YCRHGEgIP3ZVwSLK10taTmHhsKhWPya-l7qA24XD3OlBcrXe6WfMdVQh7q00KJQMG0P4pvevBB-zSixSuMx4DmN9SsQ4JZSx-3jn2XvW8qO_S7-II8nebHXbCMz83acRilZUTw81aUU5dJhLR-Y38z9ZvkNyoGjpuInCguKYS_IOJMB5V1Vj7VC47F3N80lk4Fdl_i-IXpYw7uGCIvK_EhBX2QprbZlkPTvclJ1sBGVy9WG57MQ2P0mMh9JO6xMqqCX6TXoFVJMo3hGtjINXZmAxkh-Hs4l1QMheaJBxClGEmhwAbfOwwaFeGbKXfIRos9yqgC6cdB7CJDhNQmqabAVlzInp0zGnlxt9tPsInZF-jGhWJnbG9I3Z7qzrHpUoYHD7bsmaPfeyMpaywYbRu8KgTCN_iukWz5UOc7iGrzA1k-_QKNUF7IoCK9nMOK0EHcLwFoOHusoXWW8AlHUto28Hg0gEZYQWLW7s0TRq-XFwdt5MW5PuFtRDmU6QVt2E4QLfzghwvJvVGPrOvtyJbcEorVm9I0taYvYJgaLn9VFW7No4H_V9xz0CVRXT63fshZnUV_Ggx3s0N9eZToKnb_AC-l7HyxGb3mKXypLuNl7ZDQdz-ONRc8s7-7BiaCAGPjbUE1d_R5a6F4STBJyXoq4LENS9o8PdrumbhdCZvzk1aT3jdyTldlCi0chUmz8jP1FdQ6Yfdte2UYzHnGs8pKHcE4OZlepf-Jnb6PY2svG6TWJby9hbMq1XYwFgmUvcnJELk_WDLQW3lXsa9YnOnX5lZBqyIqxYhQQXEJTtxdmcJfE1pwzSOiXvlh6UIBs_2MVLRr3Dc8jhc5qp8YjgV2pYa.1522243813342.1209600000.MQ38q8xYZeHYu454GB5ZPUpQ-yvZ0ZsHya8VOcIFqOQ","description":""},{"key":"Host","value":"auth.uber.com","description":""},{"key":"Accept","value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","description":""},{"key":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-J701F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Mobile Safari/537.36","description":""},{"key":"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","value":"1","description":""},{"key":"Connection","value":"keep-alive","description":""},{"key":"Accept-Encoding","value":"gzip, deflate","description":""},{"key":"Accept-Language","value":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9","description":""}]
```

The Response coming "Too many requests", after that onLoginError() called with CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE error.

Another thing is that, maximum time **Uber SMS gateway is not working** when I try to login (2 factor verification), thus OTP is not coming. I have also tried adding another developer in the developer dashboard, but They are also unable to get OTP when try to login.

- Note 1 : The redirect url I am using in my app is exactly same as I am using in my developer dashboard.
- Note 2 : Previously my code was working perfectly in the sandbox environment (with sample uber account), but now it is not working after I have changed to the new account. So, I suppose the code is not the problem.
- Note 3 : The previous email id linked with this app for Uber was *msayan64@gmail.com*
- Note 4 : The App is going to publish very soon, and it is using Uber as a value addition.

Questions:

- Are there any changes required to my code?
- Can using the sandbox mode be a problem?
- If I need to give the App URI as the redirect URI, what should be the format (suppose the package name (App id) is com.example.app)?
- When will be the SMS gateway work?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: No problem. Note that this post feels like it's addressed to Uber staff, and while Uber employees may read Stack Overflow, the site is not intended for support issues, and broadly your audience should be thought of as fellow users of the Uber platform. They obviously can't look up your email ID in Uber's systems.